# I need to get a slideshow working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

This my code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Roohi Health Screnning</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="roohiSTYLE.css">
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
          <script src="bjqs.min.js"></script>


          <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#banner-fade').bjqs({
        'height' : 320,
        'width' : 620,
        'responsive' : true
    });
});
            </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
        <header>
            <h1>Roohisd page<h1> 
        </header>
        <section>
        <!-- Content Starts Here -->
        <header>
            <h1>Welcome to My Site</h1>
            <p>These pages are the work of Me</p>
        </header>

            <nav id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="Roohi.html">Roohi</a></li>
                <li><a href="Service.html">Service</a></li>
                <li><a href="Products.html">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="About-us.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="findus.html">Find Us</a></li>
            </ul> 
            </nav>


                <div id="my-slideshow">
                <ul class="bjqs">

                <li><img src="images/bloodPresure.jpg"/></li>
                <li><img src="images/Cholesterol.jpg"/></li>
                <li><img src="images/diabetes.jpg"/></li>
            </ul>
            </div>





        <!-- Content Ends Here -->
        </section>

    </div>
    </body>
</html>
enter code here
```

**CSS**

```
body
{
width:800px;
margin:0 auto;
background-color:white;
}

#navigation ul
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style-type:0;
text-align: center;
}

#navigation ul li 
{
display: inline;
color: black;
}

#navigation ul li a
{
text-decoration: none;
padding: .2em 1em;
color: black;
background-color: orange;
}
```

I am trying to do a slide show in my HTML file. There is also javascript so please can soembody help to get the slideshow working i have been trying all day thank you very much

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: it just displays the images not as i want in a slideshow

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your JS code. If you could include it in your question or make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) it would be much easier to help you.

Comment: could you solve the problem ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replace the element you are working on, which is `#my-slideshow`, not `#banner-fade` :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#my-slideshow').bjqs({
        'height' : 320,
        'width' : 620,
        'responsive' : true
    });
});
```

And style the slider to your taste.

#### JS Fiddle Demo

Comment: it still doesn't work could i send you the files to have a look i tried the whole day D:

Comment: I don't have any files, check out the jsFiddle Demo

Comment: i did could I send the files to have a look i send you the files !!

Comment: Oh, okay, post a link if you want to.

Comment: is something wrong with this ---> html>
 <head>
  <title>Roohi Health Screnning</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="roohiSTYLE.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bjqs.min.js"></script>

Comment: is easier to send the files over there

Comment: i zipped file and now ??

Comment: Upload it to [ge.tt](http://ge.tt/) and give me the link you get in your address bar after that.

Comment: http://ge.tt/1aFcNyh1/v/0

Comment: http://ge.tt/13ScOyh1/v/0 There you go, you did not define the right path to the bjqs javascript, and to the bjqs css file.

Comment: can i ask u something else sorry to bother u ??

Comment: how can i make a nice slide show with a left and right arrow ???

Comment: http://ge.tt/3bA3Uyh1/v/0 You could replace the default buttons (see the JS in index.html) and style them (see bjqs.css).

Comment: thank you i  knwo how to use html and css i m new to jquery

Comment: but inoticed is not responsive anymore :S

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
  <title>Roohi Health Screnning</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="roohiSTYLE.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bjqs.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bjqs-1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#my-slideshow').bjqs({
      'height' : 320,
      'width' : 620,
      '  responsive' : true
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <header>
      <h1>Roohisd page<h1> 
      </header>
      <section>
        <!-- Content Starts Here -->
        <header>
          <h1>Welcome to My Site</h1>
          <p>These pages are the work of Me</p>
        </header>

        <nav id="navigation">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="Roohi.html">Roohi</a></li>
            <li><a href="Service.html">Service</a></li>
            <li><a href="Products.html">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="About-us.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="findus.html">Find Us</a></li>
          </ul> 
        </nav>


        <div id="my-slideshow">
          <ul class="bjqs">

            <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/620/320/city/7"/></li>
            <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/620/320/city/4"/></li>
            <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/620/320/city/3"/></li>
          </ul>
        </div>





        <!-- Content Ends Here -->
      </section>

    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: First you have to add 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="bjqs.css">

in your HEADER section.

Change:
<script src="bjqs.js"></script> into

<script src="js/bjqs-1.3.min.js"></script>
(or there, where you have the JS-file)